# What format is a newly created Image object from PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, file-type

`PIL.Image.New()` creates a new image object. However, what are the parameters of the object? `Compressed`, `non-compressed`, `lossy`...? I can't seem to file anything from the documentation.

Comment: Compressed and lossy are properties of image *files*, not of images in memory.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this. Does this mean there's no specific limitation to memory images created from PIL?

Comment: The image in memory is just a two-dimensional array of pixels (in any of several formats - grayscale, palette, true color, etc.).  If the pixels were compressed, you wouldn't be able to modify them individually, which would defeat the whole purpose of having an image in memory.  Compression only comes into play when you save the image to disk.